# Powerful non-gaming 17.3'' laptop

Tags: laptop

I'm looking for a powerful non-gaming laptop; i will mostly work with CAD and finite element analysis software (ANSYS) and some occasional gaming (like Starcraft 2). I also inted to dual boot (Ubuntu/Windows).

I don't like gaming laptops, mostly because they're very expensive and i don't like their colorful-aggresive design.

This is a must:

- 17.3'' screen (minimum FHD)
- 2 tb HDD
- Core i7 processor
- At least 8 GB of RAM

I don't really care for the weight or the battery duration, also not interested in touch screen; i want it to be durable and reliable and with a sleek design.

So far the only laptop meets most of my requierements is the [MSI PE70](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/PE70-2QE.html#hero-overview); altough it is a bit expensive i like it. However i ask because i want to know if there is a better option in the market.

Comment: Well, the PE70 is actually a gaming laptop.  Most of MSI's gaming series are not all that flashy.

Answer (score 3):

As far as something not too garish, and can be configured to meet your specifications, I would suggest the [Sager NP3673](https://www.sagernotebook.com/Notebook-NP3673.html)

1. 6th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ Processor
2. 17.3" Full HD Matte Display
3. Intel HD Graphics 530
4. 8GB DDR4 at 2400MHz *upgradable*
5. 1TB 7200rpm SATA2 HDD *upgradable*
6. 8X DVD±R/RW/4X +DL Super-Multi Drive
7. Intel Wireless-AC 3165 + Bluetooth *upgradable*
8. White-LED illuminated keyboard
9. Windows® 10 Home 64-Bit Edition *upgradable*

There are a lot of customization options through Sager's online store, such as options for an m.2 drive for your OS or extra storage.